# MySQL - Retrieving data without duplication

Tags: php, mysql

So in my SQL table I have this situation.

One item (that has a unique ID) can have photos associated with it.

I need to get all of the information on an item and both of the photos in one record (or row to be more precise).

My current query is:

```
SELECT ultrait_wpl_properties.id, location1_name, location3_name, location4_name, field_312, field_42, post_code, lot_area, living_area, price, bedrooms, bathrooms, field_308, googlemap_lt, googlemap_ln, street, street_no, ultrait_wpl_property_types.name, property_title, build_year, add_date, ultrait_wpl_items.item_name 
    FROM ultrait_wpl_properties 
    JOIN ultrait_wpl_property_types ON ultrait_wpl_properties.property_type = ultrait_wpl_property_types.id 
    JOIN ultrait_wpl_items ON ultrait_wpl_properties.id = ultrait_wpl_items.parent_id 
    ORDER BY ultrait_wpl_properties.id ";
```

From this query i get all of the information I need and the picture. The issue with my current approach is if there is more than one picture i get a duplicated row when my query executes. Is there a way around this?

I ask as I later use this data and export it to an xml file but because this query returns a duplicate record per every photo. An XML file with one item but 5 pictures will return 5 identical nodes but with different image URLs.

Comment: Could you show us what you have and what resuls you are expecting?

Comment: Is the record *actually* duplicated or is the value in `ultrait_wpl_items.item_name` different in each case? (I'm guessing it is)

Comment: What result do you want? Just one of the several photos? Or a list of them all in one row? Or just two? Which two?

Comment: Basically the item_name is different but everything else is the same, as you'd expect but I've been trying for hours to see if there was a way to get all the field data and both images without duplicates

Comment: @Blorange2, please clarify. It seems you have a one-to-many relationship between the rows in `ultrait_wpl_properties` and those in `ultraip_wpl_items`.  It seems that you expect, but cannot guarantee, that there will be exactly two `ultraip_wpl_items` rows for every `ultrait_wpl_properties` row. To generate your result set correctly and robustly, you're going to need to know how to tell which is the *first* and *second* item for each property. We can't begin to tell from your question how to do that. You need to sort out some *business rules* here to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

rewrite your query as follows

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ultrait_wpl_properties.id,
    location1_name,
    location3_name,
    location4_name,
    field_312,
    field_42,
    post_code,
    lot_area,
    living_area,
    price,
    bedrooms,
    bathrooms,
    field_308,
    googlemap_lt,
    googlemap_ln,
    street,
    street_no,
    ultrait_wpl_property_types.name,
    property_title,
    build_year,
    add_date,
    ultrait_wpl_items.item_name
FROM
    ultrait_wpl_properties
INNER JOIN
    ultrait_wpl_property_types ON
        ultrait_wpl_properties.property_type = ultrait_wpl_property_types.id
INNER JOIN
    ultrait_wpl_items ON 
        ultrait_wpl_properties.id = ultrait_wpl_items.parent_id
ORDER BY
    ultrait_wpl_properties.id
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but I think im going to have to restructure my thinking as i need all the fields but i also need every image. It's a bit tedious I know

Comment: The value on `ultrait_wpl_items.item_name` changes with each record so they **are** distinct records already - this answer won't actually solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
   SELECT ultrait_wpl_properties.id,
          (all those other columns),
          GROUP_CONCAT(ultrait_wpl_items.item_name) items
     FROM  ultrait_wpl_properties
    INNER JOIN ultrait_wpl_property_types 
              ON ultrait_wpl_properties.property_type = ultrait_wpl_property_types.id
     LEFT JOIN ultrait_wpl_items 
              ON ultrait_wpl_properties.id = ultrait_wpl_items.parent_id
    GROUP BY ultrait_wpl_properties.id
```

It uses the [notorious non-standard `GROUP BY` extension in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html), so it might yield slightly strange results. But it will yield a comma-separated list of your `item_name` columns for each `id`.

The `LEFT JOIN` makes it work correctly for `id` values lacking any images.

Comment: This works great but is there a way to seperate them out a bit?